# Why do the power spectral density estimates from matplotlib.mlab.psd and scipy.signal.welch differ when the number of points per window is even?

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, signal-processing, discrete-mathematics, mlab

`matplotlib.mlab.psd(...)` and `scipy.signal.welch(...)` both implement Welch's average periodogram method to estimate the power spectral density (PSD) of a signal. Assuming equivalent parameters are passed to each function, the returned PSD should be equivalent.

However, using a simple sinusoidal test function, there are systematic differences between the two methods when the number of points used per window (the `nperseg` keyword for `scipy.signal.welch`; the `NFFT` keyword for `mlab.psd`) is *even*, as shown below for the case of 64 points per window

[image: even number of points per window]

The top plot shows the PSD computed via both methods, while the bottom plot displays their relative error (i.e. the absolute difference of the two PSDs divided by their absolute average). A larger relative error is indicative of larger disagreement between the two methods.

The two functions have much better agreement when the number of points used per window is *odd*, as shown below for the *same* signal but processed with 65 points per window

[image: odd number of points per window]

Adding other features to the signal (e.g. noise) somewhat diminishes this effect, but it is still present, with relative errors of ~10% between the two methods when an even number of points is used per window. (I realize the relative error at the very highest frequency for the PSDs computed with 65 points per window above is relatively large. However, this is at the signal's Nyquist frequency, and I'm not too concerned about features at such high frequencies. I'm more concerned about the large and systematic relative error across the majority of the signal's bandwidth when the number of points per window is even).

Is there a reason for this discrepancy? Is one method preferable to the other in terms of accuracy? I am using scipy version 0.16.0 and matplotlib version 1.4.3.

The code used to generate the above plots is included below. For a pure sinusoidal signal, set `A_noise = 0`; for a noisy signal, set `A_noise` to a finite value.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import welch
from matplotlib import mlab

# Sampling information
Fs = 200.
t0 = 0
tf = 10
t = np.arange(t0, tf, 1. / Fs)

# Pure sinusoidal signal
f0 = 27.
y = np.cos(2 * np.pi * f0 * t)

# Add in some white noise
A_noise = 1e-3
y += (A_noise * np.random.randn(len(y)))

nperseg = 64    # even
# nperseg = 65  # odd

if nperseg > len(y):
    raise ValueError('nperseg > len(y); preventing unintentional zero padding')

# Compute PSD with `scipy.signal.welch`
f_welch, S_welch = welch(
    y, fs=Fs, nperseg=nperseg, noverlap=(nperseg // 2),
    detrend=None, scaling='density', window='hanning')

# Compute PSD with `matplotlib.mlab.psd`, using parameters that are
# *equivalent* to those used in `scipy.signal.welch` above
S_mlab, f_mlab = mlab.psd(
    y, Fs=Fs, NFFT=nperseg, noverlap=(nperseg // 2),
    detrend=None, scale_by_freq=True, window=mlab.window_hanning)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

# Plot PSD computed via both methods
axes[0].loglog(f_welch, S_welch, '-s')
axes[0].loglog(f_mlab, S_mlab, '-^')
axes[0].set_xlabel('f')
axes[0].set_ylabel('PSD')
axes[0].legend(['scipy.signal.welch', 'mlab.psd'], loc='upper left')

# Plot relative error
delta = np.abs(S_welch - S_mlab)
avg = 0.5 * np.abs(S_welch + S_mlab)
relative_error = delta / avg
axes[1].loglog(f_welch, relative_error, 'k')
axes[1].set_xlabel('f')
axes[1].set_ylabel('relative error')

plt.suptitle('nperseg = %i' % nperseg)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the parameters may appear to be equivalent, the window parameter may slightly differ for even sized window. More specifically, unless provided a specific window vector, the window used by scipy's `welch` function is generated with

```
win = get_window(window, nperseg)
```

which uses the default parameter `fftbins=True`, and according to [scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.get_window.html):

> If True, create a “periodic” window ready to use with ifftshift and be multiplied by the result of an fft (SEE ALSO fftfreq).

This result in a different generated window for even lengths. From [this section of the Window function entry on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Symmetry), this could give you a slight performance advantage over Matplotlib's `window_hanning` which always returns the symmetric version.

To use the same window you can explicitly specify the window vector to both PSD estimation functions. You could for example compute this window with:

```
win = scipy.signal.get_window('hanning',nperseg)
```

Using this window as parameter (with `window=win` in both functions) would give the following plot where you may notice a much closer agreement between the two PSD estimation functions:

[image: PSD estimates]

Alternatively, assuming you do not want the periodic window property, you could also use:

```
win = mlab.window_hanning(np.ones(nperseg)) # or
win = scipy.signal.get_window('hanning',nperseg,fftbins=False)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I was not aware of "symmetric" vs. "periodic" windowing functions, so the link to the background information was particularly useful :)